# Where is svcutil.exe if i am using visual studio 2012?

Tags: svcutil.exe

I read a book "Pro c# 2010 and the .net 4 Platform" Andrew Troelsen.I stuck on page 926 "using
svcutil.exe" 
Where is svcutil.exe in windows 7 if i am using  visual studio 2012?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: there is written C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin for visual studio 2010

Comment: No it doesn't. Where did you see that? Also, I guess you could invoke it from VS Command Prompt directly, unless you want the path for some other reason.

Answer (score 8):

The svcutil.exe tool is added when you install the .net framework and you can find on many places, varying of the framework installed, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools,  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin,  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64
```

Comment: If my answer was useful for you, please Accept it.